# Android RotateAnimation: rotate compass smoothly

Tags: android, animation, compass

i have a custom compass with 3 image Views first compass direction always to north second always on direction i specify 3 proven, so i want it to rotate smoothly but when i close from reach 0 or 360 degree its like wrap round like it restart or something like that.

-i want my compass rotate smoothly without wrapping round when i close from reach some degrees.

```
``public class GeoLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private ImageView compass, satDirect;
    private TextView satName, degree, azmuthT, elevationT, skewT;
    
    private Sensor magSensor, accSensor;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private float[] lastAcc;
    private float[] lastMag;
    private float[] orientation;
    private float[] rotation;
    
    private boolean isLastAccCopied;
    private boolean isLastMagCopied;
    
    private long lastUpdateTime1, lastUpdateTime2;
    private float currentDegree1, currentDegree2;
    private float satAzmuth, dishElevation, lnbSkew;
    
    private float smoothAzimuth1 = 0f, smoothAzimuth2   = 0f;
    private static final float SMOOTHING_FACTOR = 0.1f;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geo_location);
        init();
    }
    
    private void init() {
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        satAzmuth = b.getFloat("azmuth", 0);
        dishElevation = b.getFloat("elev", 0);
        lnbSkew = b.getFloat("lnb", 0);
        compass = findViewById(R.id.compass);
        satDirect = findViewById(R.id.satD);
        satName = findViewById(R.id.satName);
        degree = findViewById(R.id.degree);
        azmuthT = findViewById(R.id.azmuth);
        azmuthT.setText(satAzmuth + "");
        elevationT = findViewById(R.id.elevation);
        elevationT.setText(dishElevation + "");
        skewT = findViewById(R.id.lnb_skew);
        skewT.setText(lnbSkew + "");
        satName.setText(b.getString("sat", ""));
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    
        lastAcc = new float[3];
        lastMag = new float[3];
        orientation = new float[3];
        rotation = new float[9];
    
        isLastAccCopied = false;
        isLastMagCopied = false;
        lastUpdateTime1 = 0;
        currentDegree1 = 0f;
    
        lastUpdateTime2 = 0;
        currentDegree2 = 0f;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    
        setNorthDirection(sensorEvent);
        setSatDirect(sensorEvent);
    
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
    
    }
    
    private  void setNorthDirection(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor == accSensor) {
    
            lastAcc = sensorEvent.values;
            isLastAccCopied = true;
        } else if (sensorEvent.sensor == magSensor) {
            lastMag = sensorEvent.values;
            isLastMagCopied = true;
        }
    
        if (isLastAccCopied || isLastMagCopied && System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdateTime2 > 250) {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, null, lastAcc, lastMag);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);
    
            float azimuthInRadiant = orientation[0];
            float azimuthInDegree = (float) Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadiant);
    
            smoothAzimuth2 = smoothAzimuth2 * (1 - SMOOTHING_FACTOR) + azimuthInDegree * SMOOTHING_FACTOR;
    
            RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree2, -smoothAzimuth2, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(0);
            rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            compass.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
            currentDegree2 = -smoothAzimuth2;
            lastUpdateTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    
    private void setSatDirect (SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (sensorEvent.sensor == accSensor) {
    
            lastAcc = sensorEvent.values;
            isLastAccCopied = true;
        } else if (sensorEvent.sensor == magSensor) {
            lastMag = sensorEvent.values;
            isLastMagCopied = true;
        }
    
        if (isLastAccCopied || isLastMagCopied && System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdateTime1 > 250) {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotation, null, lastAcc, lastMag);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(rotation, orientation);
    
            float azimuthInRadiant = orientation[0];
            float azimuthInDegree = (float) Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadiant);
    
    
            float azimuthToNilesar = azimuthInDegree - satAzmuth;
            if (azimuthToNilesar < 0f) {
                azimuthToNilesar += 360f;
            }
    
            smoothAzimuth1 = smoothAzimuth1 * (1 - SMOOTHING_FACTOR) + azimuthToNilesar * SMOOTHING_FACTOR;
            RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(currentDegree1, -smoothAzimuth1, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            satDirect.setAnimation(rotateAnimation);
            currentDegree1 = -smoothAzimuth1;
            int intDRG = (int) currentDegree1;
            degree.setText(-intDRG + "°");
            lastUpdateTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accSensor);
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accSensor);
    }
    
    public void backbtn(View view){
        onBackPressed();
    }

}
```